# col doesn't align correctly

Tags: css, angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I need to align 3 element with bootstrap. I use angular 8 so in install bootstrap, i need only css (I need only the col-md, col etc) so I do:

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

            ],
```

in my style.sass i do :

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

so in my header component i do this:

```
  <div id="test" class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12"> 
                      <div class="col-3">
                          <img id="iconn" src="assets/img/iconf.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-5">
                          <h1 id="home">HOME</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-3 offset-2">
                          <img id="log" src="assets/img/logo_f.png" class="img-responsive" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>          
      </div>
```

The problem is the  two images and the text are in the different rows but i want their in the same row.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried removing the wrapping `.col-12` element and ensuring your images scale with their containers? `.col-` elements should only be children of `.row` elements in bootstrap—not other `.col-` elements.

Answer (score 3):

you have added extra `col-12` in your code. `offset` should be 1

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <img id="iconn" src="assets/img/iconf.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <h1 id="home">HOME</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 offset-1">
            <img id="log" src="assets/img/logo_f.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
</div>
```